# RSS enclosures that do not follow the spec

Tags: rss

One of the [feeds I follow](http://feeds.feedburner.com/historyofphilosophy) has started using enclosures of the following form:

```
<enclosure>http://www.historyofphilosophy.net/sites/default/files/MP3/HoP%20140%20-%20By%20All%20Means%20Necessary%20-%20Avicenna%20on%20God.mp3</enclosure>
```

This, if I understand correctly, doesn't conform to the RSS 2.0 specs, which, rather, proposes enclosures of the form

```
<enclosure url="http://www.scripting.com/mp3s/weatherReportSuite.mp3" length="12216320" type="audio/mpeg" />
```

My question is whether the former, abnormal enclosures are frequent, and something a feed aggregator should be expected to parse.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cvq67iQpk2C7ufOsefsfKnGCXeUIv46NQHbnHkm8PtU/edit

Comment: Oh! The publisher is an idiot. Answer deleted as irrelevant.